# How to keep subscriber after onError(RxJava)

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

1st, I tried

```
// used retrofit
public interface ApiService {
    @GET(/get_some_data)
    Observable<SomeData> getSomeData();
}



// clickStream created by onClick event
// No.1
clickStream
    .flatMap(e -> apiService.getSomeData())
    .subscribe(
        success -> Log.d("tag", "success"),
        error -> Log.d("tag", "error"),
        () -> Log.d("tag", "complete"))
```

this is fine if **getSomeData()** is success.
I can get some data each click.

but if occur error, unsubscribed.
(so click is not works after error)

---

2nd, I tried below.(with onErrorResumeNext) but **unsubscribed**.

(didn't call onError, but called onComplete. so unsubscribed)

```
// No.2
clickStream
    .flatMap(e -> apiService.getSomeData())
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())  // add this line
    .subscribe(
        success -> Log.d("tag", "success"),
        error -> Log.d("tag", "error"),
        () -> Log.d("tag", "complete"))
```

---

3rd, I tried below.(with retry)

```
// No.3
clickStream
    .flatMap(e -> apiService.getSomeData())
    .retry(5)                                            // add this line
    .subscribe(
        success -> Log.d("tag", "success"),
        error -> Log.d("tag", "error"),
        () -> Log.d("tag", "complete"))
```

this is better than No.1. but unscribed.

---

I want to make refresh button that works after error.

I want to know

1. Can I keep or re-subscribe subscriber?
2. Is this a proper way in Rxjava?

sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Nr. 2 was quite close - try this:

```
clickStream
.flatMap(e -> apiService.getSomeData()
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty()))  // add this line
.subscribe(
    success -> Log.d("tag", "success"),
    error -> Log.d("tag", "error"),
    () -> Log.d("tag", "complete"))
```

Notice that I just moved one closing parenthesis so that the `onErrorResumeNext` is now called after *every* error and is part of the "inner" Observable.

Comment: It worked! I can keep subscriber after onError. The key is "**inner** Observable". thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course - either you get `onError` or you can keep using the `Subscriber`, but not both. What you could do, though, is emitting some error message type: `throwable -> Observable.just(new ThereWasSomeProblemWithTheApi()))`. The `T` in `Observable<T>` would then have to be some common interface that's shared by `ThereWasSomeProblemWithTheApi` and your actual data type.